# jvm.dll seems incompatible with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, jvm, msvcrt

I am dynamically loading (server) jvm.dll into my 64-bit Visual Studio 2013 C++ application using LoadLibrary(), in order to execute native Java code using JNI.

In the VS debugger, I am getting a number of access violations as the dll is being loaded (yet things seem to work if I 'continue' after these); and then a hard crash when some JNI calls are being invoked.  I have tried jvm.dll's from Java 1.7 and Java 1.8, with the same issues.

I suspect the issue to be runtime library incompatibility.  Dependency walker indicates that even the latest jvm.dll depends on msvcr100.dll (from Visual Studio 2010).  I have heard dire warnings of the consequences of using incompatible runtime versions; and have seen the results first hand in other instances.

Has anyone else run into this problem?  Is there any version of jvm.dll available that is compiled against Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Just recently (Feb 2015) I compiled a JNI application which invokes the JVM to run a Java program.  I used the most recent JRE version (1.8.0_31) and Visual Studio 2013. I am also loading the jvm.dll at runtime.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28778933/975724) if you want to see how I setup my JNI calls.

So it is possible...
Make sure that the JRE containing jvm.dll is built for the same architecture (32bit or 64bit) as your Visual Studio project.  If you are using 64bit, you may need to add the `x64` as your configuration.  To do this go to:

`Solution --> Properties --> Configuration Properties`

Also make sure your includes/libraries are correct.
For my project, I needed to include the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\include
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\include\win32
```

Also, I needed to include `jvm.lib` which is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib
```

Make sure you also add the `jvm.lib` to your linker input.  Alternatively you can use the preprocessor:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "jvm.lib")
```

Hopefully, this should help get your project configured right.  If you are still having errors, I would recommend uninstalling Java completely, and re-installing after.  Perhaps the same with Visual Studio 2013 as well...