# Deploying JRE via JNI: jvm.dll not designed to run on Windows or [......]

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

So I'm creating a Win32 application that packages the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) as a resource.  The application extracts the resource to the disk and unzips it.  Now, I would like to use this JRE in order to run a Java program using the invocation API.  As soon as I changed to program to point to the extracted JRE's jvm.dll instead of the installed JRE (which is what I copied), I received this error:

> <jre-path>\jre1.8.0_31\bin\server\jvm.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.  Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x000012f

[image: jvm.dll error message]

What I am hoping to do with this question is to document this error as well as what caused it. And if possible, find a solution so I can reference the extracted JRE.

Let me give some specifics to my environment.  First of all I'm running Windows 10 Tech Preview.  My OS, my program, and the JRE I copied from the installation are all 64-bit.  Also, when I had my program point to the installed JRE, it worked fine, the problem is only with the copied JRE.

And some code for reference of what I'm doing:

```
typedef jint (JNICALL *CreateJVMFunc)(JavaVM **pvm, void **penv, void *args);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //For brevity I am omitting the extraction/unzipping.
    //I am using libzip to do the unzipping which uses zlib
    //for dealing with the compression/decrompression.
    //Likewise, I am also omitting the error checking for brevity.

    //Assume at this point the JRE folder exists in the same location
    //as this program's executable file.  I am accessing the jvm.dll
    //using a relative file path.

    //Load the Java virtual machine inside of the packaged JRE.
    //This is where that error occurs.
    //LoadLibrary is necessary because I must connect to the DLL after
    //it has been unpacked.
    HMODULE jvmDll = LoadLibrary(_T("jre1.8.0_31\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"));
    CreateJVMFunc CreateJVM = (CreateJVMFunc)GetProcAddress(jvmDll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

    //Start the Java virtual machine.
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/Nicholas/Documents/Programming Projects/Java Projects/JVM Launcher Test/JVM Launcher Test.jar"
    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vmArgs.nOptions = 1;
    vmArgs.options = options;
    vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    int retVal = CreateJVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vmArgs);
    delete[] options;

    //Instantiate the program.
    jclass mainClass = env->FindClass("jvmlauncher/test/Application");
    jmethodID mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, mainMethod, NULL);

    //Cleanup.
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    FreeLibrary(jvmDll);
    return 0;
}
```

So I suppose there are a few questions I would like to find answers for.

- What exactly triggers the error message?  This error is not unique to my application, so what documentation exists for that error?
- Why is the copied JRE (which is an exact copy of the installed one) not working as I expected?
- How can I correct the situation so I can use this unpacked JRE?

Comment: What else (other than copying it's files does the original JRE installer do?  I am thinking of registry changes, configuration files, COM registration, additional support dlls installed outside of the JRE folder etc.

Comment: To be honest, I was thinking the same kind of thing.  My installer just copies the files.  My understanding is that it is possible to deploy an application packaged with the JRE such that the user doesn't need to install Java via [java.com](http://java.com/en/download/) to run a Java program.  The goal is to have the use be able to just run the .exe file and everything 'just works' even if they did not install Java.

Comment: I posted this question too quickly, I resolved the issue..  The problem is that I didn't verify the correctness of the unzipped file.   When I copy the JRE to the desired path, it works.  However, I still get that error when running the program in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly triggers the error message? This error is not unique to my application, so what documentation exists for that error?

The error message is right.  Something was wrong with my custom installation.  Apparently the files lost data when extracted from the executable file.
After literally copying in the currently installed JRE, everything works!

> Why is the copied JRE (which is an exact copy of the installed one) not working as I expected?

Because it is not an "exact" copy.

> How can I correct the situation so I can use this unpacked JRE?

This is no longer an issue because it was a fault on my end.  The extraction wasn't done correctly.

#### PS:  Enjoy the JNI code, hopefully it will help someone out later to do this!

Answer (score 0):

**Just install 32 bit JDK Version and run Android Studio.**
If Android Studio does not detect 32 bit JDK itself chnage your Environment variable